# Controlling nonstandard classes with pywinauto

Tags: python, combobox, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto in order to ease my work with certain program. I would like to select in this [combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHbHV.png) item "vs. Reference". I used `app['Setup Potentiodynamic Experiment'].PrintControlIdentifiers()` to get name and class of the combobox. Python returned the following:

```
TComboDJ - 'b'vs. Open Circuit''   (L987, T424, R1094, B445)

'b'TComboDJ5''
'b'vs. Open Circuit3''
'b'vs. Open CircuitTComboDJ3''
```

So, to do what I want, I used this:

```
app['Setup Potentiodynamic Experiment']["TComboDJ5"].Select("vs. Reference")
```

And the following error appeared:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\PY\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1550, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "E:/Python projects/test/test.py", line 40, in createxp
    app['Setup Potentiodynamic Experiment']["TComboDJ5"].Select("vs. Reference")
  File "E:\PY\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 245, in __getattr__
    return getattr(ctrls[-1], attr)
AttributeError: 'HwndWrapper' object has no attribute 'Select'
```

As far as I understand, pywinauto can't recognize the combobox as a combobox. Can something be done about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComboBoxWrapper` can be created explicitly:

```
from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import ComboBoxWrapper
hwnd_wr = app['Setup Potentiodynamic Experiment']["TComboDJ5"].WrapperObject()
combo = ComboBoxWrapper(hwnd_wr)
combo.Select("vs. Reference")
```

Of course it would work if the combo box could respond to standard window messages like `CB_GETCOUNT`. And the output tells you that combined `<title><item_text>` access names are fortunately available.